# Function that is uniformly continuous but not bounded?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I've been given the following question but I'm unsure if there are actually any answers:

> Give examples of functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which are uniformly continuous such that $f$ is not bounded but $g$ is bounded.

I know that if $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous then $f$ is bounded so surely there is no such example for $f$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=A$?

Comment: Wonderful. The shortest answers are the best answers.

Comment: @MattN. Thanks!